# undefined symbol: memset, version GLIBC_2.2.5

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am getting this:

./ListBench: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: memset, version GLIBC_2.2.5

Why is memset undefined in libc.so?

```
# ldd /usr/lib/foo.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff167ff000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f907eb000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2f905e3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2f903c6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f90d86000)

# nm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memset
nm: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: no symbols

# objdump -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memset
00000000000904e0 g    DF .text  0000000000000066  GLIBC_2.2.5 wmemset
00000000000f0620 g    DF .text  0000000000000017  GLIBC_2.4   __wmemset_chk
0000000000083690 g   iD  .text  0000000000000029  GLIBC_2.2.5 memset
00000000000ecec0 g   iD  .text  0000000000000029  GLIBC_2.3.4 __memset_chk

# ldd --version
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38) 2.13
```

foo.so is compiled using

```
gcc -shared -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -fPIC -Wall -Wno-unused -fno-strict-aliasing  -o libfoo.so sync.o ksnap.o time_util.o bitmap.o -lc -pthread -lrt;
```

Comment: Show the output of 'objdump -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memset'.

Comment: Is it `foo.so`  or `libfoo.so`? Perhaps you have two different files!!

Comment: its libfoo.so sorry for the typo

Comment: is there some libc version mismatch problem why is it showing glibc_2.2.5 although glibc seems to be at version 2.13?

Comment: For the mem* and str* functions, GCC appears to optimize with '__builtin_' mostly when the size is constant (known at compile time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a wrong order of linking options (-lfoo had to be last). Reordering them solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

look for dynamic symbols, e.g.

```
 nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memset
 00000000000fb210 i __memset_chk
 00000000000fe910 T __wmemset_chk
 0000000000086c30 i memset
 000000000009cb00 T wmemset
```

and quite often (depending upon optimization level and compiler used when compiling  your `/usr/lib/foo.so` shared object) `memset` could either be [inlined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) or magically compiled as `__builtin_memset` (see [other builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) of GCC). On my Debian/Sid/x86-64 `memset`is a macro in `/usr/include/bits/string.h` included from `<string.h>`

Check carefully that you have indeed `#include<string.h>` in every C source file calling `memset` ... Don't forget to always pass `-Wall` to `gcc` (it would warn if you forgot the inclusion)...

Comment: thanks, I essentially get the same output as you on nm -D. Any idea how to avoid the undefined symbol runtime error in this case?

Comment: Show the source code of your `foo.so` calling `memset` and how you are compiling it.

Comment: string.h is included everywhere. my string.h (no macro here): /* Set N bytes of S to C.  */
extern void *memset (void *__s, int __c, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));